# enabling ufw disables some of the settings in sysctl.conf

Tags: firewall, ufw, sysctl

When I add rules to ufw and then enable it, some of my settings in `sysctl.conf` become void so I have to do `sysctl -p` after doing `ufw enable`.

So for example one of my settings in `sysctl.conf` is to not reply to ping, after enabling ufw, you can ping the server again.

Why is this?

Here are some of the settings in my `sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
kernel.panic = 10
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
kernel.sysrq = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1204 65000
net.core.rmem_max = 262140
net.core.rmem_default = 262140
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 131072 262140
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 131072 262140
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60000
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
```

EDIT

Thank you Aaron!
I have come to rely on Google so much that I didn't think of inspecting the config files for ufw in etc - and there it was, so easy!

For anyone looking for an answer to this, you can either set your config in that file or even better, edit `/etc/default/ufw` file so it uses the system default `sysctl.conf` file in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UncomplicatedFirewall**

UFW has it's own sysctl settings that can override the system global settings.

Please take a look at:

```
/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
```

If that file does not exist, grep through the files in that directory for anything calling sysctl.